# Get key names from JSON array

Tags: php, json, key

I need do extract all cpu ids from this kind of JSON response:

```
$response = json_decode('{
  "code": 26,
  "result": {
    "0": {
      "cpu": {
        "423": {
          "prod": "Intel",
          "model": "i5-8300H",
        },
        "424": {
          "prod": "Intel",
          "model": "i7-8750H",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}');
```

I managed to obtain first id `423` with this code:

```
$response = $response->result;
foreach ($response as $item) {
            $key = key((array)$item->cpu);
        }
```

but I can't find the way to get the reset, in this case `424`. How can I do it?

Comment: Your `$response` assignment is not valid PHP syntax.

Comment: Did you mean to write `$response = json_decode('{...}');`

Comment: Use [`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) instead of `key()`;

Comment: fixed the syntax

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't use the `true` second argument to `json_decode()`, all the elements are being parsed as objects, not arrays. Use `json_decode(..., true)` to get arrays.

Then you can use `array_keys()` to get all the keys of the `cpu` array.

```
$response = json_decode('
{
  "code": 26,
  "result": {
    "0": {
      "cpu": {
        "423": {
          "prod": "Intel",
          "model": "i5-8300H"
        },
        "424": {
          "prod": "Intel",
          "model": "i7-8750H"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}', true);
$response = $response['result'];
foreach ($response as $item) {
    $keys = array_keys($item['cpu']);
    var_dump($keys);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate over the `cpu` values as well; you can extract the key directly in the `foreach`:

```
$results = $response->result;
foreach ($results as $item) {
    foreach ($item->cpu as $key => $cpu) {
        echo "$key\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
423
424
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jckg6)